# How can I differenciate this two operator overloading?

Tags: c++, reference, operator-overloading, operators, overloading

I am trying to clone the std::map class in c++; I use a std::vector which stores std::pair. And now I am implementing the [] operator. I made two definitions, one is const to acces without modifying and the other is not const.

When compiling it tells me that there is no difference.

This are the declarations:
Using this template:

```cpp
template<class TClau, class TValor>
```

```cpp
TValor& operator[](const TClau& clau);
const TValor& operator[](const TClau& clau);
```

And this are the definitions:

```cpp
//m_map is the actual vector with pairs.

template<class TClau, class TValor>
TValor& Map<TClau, TValor>::operator[](const TClau& clau) {
    int l = 0, r = m_length - 1;
    int m;
    if (r >= l) {
        while (r >= l) {
            m = l + (r - l) / 2;
            if (m_map[m] == clau)
                return m_map[m].second;
            if (m_map[m] > clau)
                r = m - 1;

            l = m + 1;
        }
    }
    return TValor;
}

template<class TClau, class TValor>
const TValor& Map<TClau, TValor>::operator[](const TClau& clau) {
    int l = 0, r = m_length - 1;
    int m;
    if (r >= l) {
        while (r >= l) {
            m = l + (r - l) / 2;
            if (m_map[m] == clau)
                return m_map[m].second;
            if (m_map[m] > clau)
                r = m - 1;

            l = m + 1;
        }
    }
    return aux;
}
```

I would appriciate if someone could help me with this.

Comment: Returning a `const TValor&` implies that this overload is meant to be called on a const `Map<TClau, TValor>` only. If this is so, do `const TValor& operator[](const TClau& clau) const;`

Comment: @Nil folquer covarrubias Overloading of functions can't be done only by changing the return type. You need to change at least one parameter, or what you should do here is to declare the function returning the `const` reference as itself being `const`, like `const TValor& Map<TClau, TValor>::operator[](const TClau& clau) const`. Note the const at the end of the declaration.

Comment: Okey that worked. Now I have another problem. Later I make a map where TClau is another class with an operator==. When I am comparing, it gives me a ` binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type (or there is no acceptable conversion)` Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These operators differ only by the return type.

```
TValor& operator[](const TClau& clau);
const TValor& operator[](const TClau& clau);
```

The second operator should be declared with the qualifier const

```
const TValor& operator[](const TClau& clau) const;
```

In this case the declarations of the operators are different.

The first operator will be called for a non-constant object and the second operator will be called for a constant object.

Comment: Okey that worked. Now I have another problem. Later I make a map where TClau is another class with an operator==. When I am comparing, it gives me a ` binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type (or there is no acceptable conversion)` Any ideas?

Comment: @Nilfolquercovarrubias It ia another question. Close the current question and create a new one.